# Escape CSV file with sed or other command line tool

Tags: regex, linux, csv, sed, command-line

I have the following CSV, separated by "|".

```
101|abc|this is desc|2017
102|xyz|"thie is a long desc
des for xyz continue here."|2017
```

I have two records, `101` and `102`. 102 record is divided into 2 lines. How can I used `sed` or other command line tools to escape the new line character with "/"?

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: Isn't the newline the end of record? If so, the only reason a newline would not be the eor is if a field recognizes quotes where it could be extended with embedded newlines. Don't csv parsers interpret this correctly, or what is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

For your specific case you can use this.

`$ cat lll
101|abc|this is desc|2017
102|xyz|"thie is a long desc
des for xyz continue here."|2017
105|xyz|"thie is a long desc
des for xyz continue here."|2017
101|abc|this is desc|2017
101|abc|this is desc|2017
101|abc|this is desc|2017
105|xyz|"thie is a long desc
des for xyz continue here."|2017`

`$ perl -F'\n' -ane 'BEGIN{our $line_to_join = undef; } foreach ( @F) { if (/[a-z]+$/) { $line_to_join = $_; } elsif ($line_to_join){ print $line_to_join,"/\n",$_,"\n"; $line_to_join = undef; }else{print $_,"\n" ; $line_to_join = undef;}} ;' < lll`

Output:

`101|abc|this is desc|2017
102|xyz|"thie is a long desc/
des for xyz continue here."|2017
105|xyz|"thie is a long desc/
des for xyz continue here."|2017
101|abc|this is desc|2017
101|abc|this is desc|2017
101|abc|this is desc|2017
105|xyz|"thie is a long desc/
des for xyz continue here."|2017`

Comment: I have to make this universal, not just limit to 102

Comment: I have now used perl for the solution or you can use awk from the answer below

Answer (score 0):

`awk` is better tool to handle this.

Assuming you know how many columns are needed in each line. You can use this `awk` command:

```
awk -v n=4 -F '|' 'p+NF<n{p+=NF-1; print $0 "\\"; next} {p=0} 1' file

101|abc|this is desc|2017
102|xyz|"this is a long desc\
des for xyz continue here."|2017
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed '/102/ s#$#/&#' file11
101|abc|this is desc|2017
102|xyz|"thie is a long desc/
des for xyz continue here."|2017
```