# Perl - escaple new line character using regex in a file from the command line

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following CSV file, and need the escape the new line inside the double quote with the character "/"

```
101|abc|this is desc|2017
102|xyz|"thie is a long desc
des for xyz continue here."|2017
103|abc|this is is another long desc
and it stop here"|2017
```

and the output should looks like below file. How can I use Perl from the command to perform this?

```
101|abc|this is desc|2017
102|xyz|"thie is a long desc/
des for xyz continue here."|2017
103|bbb|"this is is another long desc/
and it stop here"|2017
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44420759/multi-line-regex-expression 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44420164/escape-csv-file-with-sed-or-other-command-line-tool

Comment: As someone with your experience should know, you will need to show the code that's causing you problems before we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you'd do it like `s =~ /(?:(?!\A)\G[^"\r\n]*\K|\|"[^"\r\n]*\K)(?<!\/)(\R)/\/$1/g`

Since you've shown no effort, you get no explanation.